# Current that flows through a 400 watts flat iron connected to a 220 volt power line

Tags: basic, electricity

**Problem:** Find the current that flows through the filament of a 400 Watts flat iron connected to a 220 volt power line.

**Attempt:** The only formula I could think of that will connect voltage and current is P = I*V, which results to I = (400) / (220) = 1.82 A.

Sadly, the answer is 500 mA. The question is how? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Obvious error in web answer , unfortunately

Comment: To confirm, P=IV, so your method of I=P/V = 400/220 = 1.82A was totally correct in using the right formula, doing the calculation correctly, and rounding to a reasonable number of significant figures for engineering. Well done.

Comment: Don't visit that site again!

Comment: +1 for asking the question. It's sometimes difficult to know whether published information is saying something you don't understand, or flat out wrong. Here, it's flat out wrong. Probably useful to post the URL as a warning to others.

Answer (score 2):

I get 1.82 Amps (not V), so it seems that the 500 mA answer you were given is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, that was an error, should be in Amps. There are many references that showcase 500 mA is the answer, sadly it doesn't show solution only the right choice out of 4 given choices.